# Json Parsing in Swift 2.0 and 3.0

Tags: json, swift, parsing

We have a problem in swift when parsing JSON. If you look at example image, you will see our problem. We get string from json. When we assign to dictionary2, we get exception:

> "Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x10652de00) to 'NSDictionary' (0x10652e2d8)."

How can we parse this? We can't update swift into latest version.

```
let urlJsonToken2 = "https://jsonservices.mywebsite.com/api/en/News"
let myURL2 = NSURL(string: urlJsonToken2)
let request2 = NSMutableURLRequest(url: myURL2 as! URL)
request2.httpMethod = "GET"
request2.addValue("Bearer "+token!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
request2.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "content-type")
request2.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request2 as URLRequest) {(data2, response2, error2) -> Void in
    if let unwrappedData2 = data2 {
        do {
            let requestReply = NSString(data: data2!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue)
            let tokenDictionary2:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData2, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            let Name = tokenDictionary2["Name"] as? String
        }
        catch {}
    }
}
task2.resume()
```

[image: Example]

Comment: What's the point of showing a fraction of code with a picture?  Everybody should give you an F.

Comment: Don't post images of code. The error tells you what you have done wrong. you are casting an array to a dictionary.

Comment: We added our code as well. @Scriptable, how can we parse array ? Could you post a sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you are trying to parse an array as a dictionary.

```
let task2 = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request2 as URLRequest) {(data2, response2, error2) -> Void in
    if let unwrappedData2 = data2 {
        do {
            guard let records = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: unwrappedData2, options: .mutableContainers) as? [[String: Any]] else {
                print("[DEBUG] - Unable to parse JSON as array")
                return
            }

            let firstRecord = records.first
            print(records.count, firstRecord)

        } catch {}
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** When using Swift, you should avoid using NS classes unless you really have to. Swift has it's own bridged types. NSDictionary = Dictionary, NSArray = Array